# Usage of Aún si

Tags: estilo

***No hay chá, aún si pidió más***

There was no more tea, but still he asked for another cup.

any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No había más té, pero aún así (él) pidió otra taza.

Answer (score 3):

The correct expression is not *aún si*, but *aun así*. Notice that *aun* has no tilde in this expression. You can [find](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=529832&langid=24) [several](http://algomasquetraducir.com/2007/11/17/aun-asi-%C2%BFcon-o-sin-tilde/) [sources](http://blog.lengua-e.com/2007/aun-con-tilde-y-aun-sin-tilde/) in the internet explaining the reason.

The full sentence would be:

> No quedaba más té, pero aun así pidió otra taza.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that "aún si" is different from "aún así". As an example:

"Aún si entreno, puede que no gane el campeonato". (Even if i train i could not win the chanpionship).